# How to combine overlapping date ranges in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date-range

I have a table „lessons_holidays“. It can contain several holiday date ranges i.e.

```
"holiday_begin"    "holiday_end" 
2016-06-15         2016-06-15
2016-06-12         2016-06-16
2016-06-15         2016-06-19
2016-06-29         2016-06-29
```

I would like to combine each entry if the date ranges overlap. And I need an output like this:

```
"holiday_begin"    "holiday_end" 
2016-06-12         2016-06-19
2016-06-29         2016-06-29
```

SQL: The following sql-statement loads all rows. Now I am stuck.

```
SELECT lh1.holiday_begin, lh1.holiday_end 
FROM local_lessons_holidays lh1 
WHERE lh1.holiday_impact = '1' AND
(DATE_FORMAT(lh1.holiday_begin, '%Y-%m') <= '2016-06' AND DATE_FORMAT(lh1.holiday_end, '%Y-%m') >= '2016-06') AND
lh1.uid = '1'
```

Comment: This is quite hard to do in MySQL.  Do you have any other databases you can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a hard problem, made harder because you are using MySQL.  Here is an idea.  Find the beginning date of all holidays in each group.  Then a cumulative sum of the flag for the "beginning" handles the groups.  The rest is just aggregation.

The following should do what you want, assuming you have no duplicate records:

```
select min(holiday_begin) as holiday_begin, max(holiday_end) as holiday_end
from (select lh.*, (@grp := @grp + group_flag) as grp
      from (select lh.*,
                   (case when not exists (select 1
                                          from lessons_holidays lh2
                                          where lh2.holiday_begin <= lh.holiday_end and
                                                lh2.holiday_end > lh.holiday_begin and
                                                (lh2.holiday_begin <> lh.holiday_begin or
                                                 lh2.holiday_end < lh.holiday_end)

                                         )
                         then 1 else 0
                    end) as group_flag
            from lessons_holidays lh
           ) lh cross join
           (select @grp := 0) params
      order by holiday_begin, holiday_end
    ) lh
group by grp;
```

If you have duplicates, just use `select distinct` on the innermost references to the table.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/59806/8) is a SQL Fiddle.

EDIT:

This version appears to work better:

```
select min(holiday_begin) as holiday_begin, max(holiday_end) as holiday_end
from (select lh.*, (@grp := @grp + group_flag) as grp
      from (select lh.*,
                   (case when not exists (select 1
                                          from lessons_holidays lh2
                                          where lh2.holiday_begin <= lh.holiday_begin and
                                                lh2.holiday_end > lh.holiday_begin and
                                                lh2.holiday_begin <> lh.holiday_begin and
                                                lh2.holiday_end <> lh.holiday_end
                                         )
                         then 1 else 0
                    end) as group_flag
            from lessons_holidays lh
           ) lh cross join
           (select @grp := 0) params
      order by holiday_begin, holiday_end
    ) lh
group by grp;
```

As illustrated [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f03b/31).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try it out later.

Comment: As result I get only: 2016-06-12 | 2016-06-29. this result can i also get by this sql statement: "SELECT MIN(holiday_begin) as holiday_begin, MAX(holiday_end) as holiday_end FROM local_lessons_holidays WHERE 1"

Comment: @Bonaparte . . . Fixed.  The problem was the overlap logic.

Comment: great! thank you! i can't vote as newbie. now i have to understand how it works ;)

Comment: @Bonaparte . . . Start with the innermost subquery and work your way out.

Comment: I just discovered that the SQL statement above also combines dates although they doesn't overlap i.e. (2016-12-23|2017-01-03) and (2017-01-30|2017-02-04). As a result I get this wrong date range (2016-12-23|2017-02-04). Now it seems to work out. I'm not sure if my changes are correct. Can you please advice me on it? Thanks in advance! WHERE lh2.holiday_begin <= lh.holiday_end AND
lh2.holiday_end > lh.holiday_begin AND
(lh2.holiday_begin <> lh.holiday_begin OR lh2.holiday_end < lh.holiday_end) AND lh2.holiday_end <> lh.holiday_end AND lh2.holiday_end > lh.holiday_end

Comment: @Bonaparte . . . If the data has only those two dates, then `group_flag` should be set to 1 for the second date.  That should put it in a different group.  Are you sure there are no intervening records?

Comment: The holidays can contain several date ranges during one month they both overlap and not. i.e. 1: (2016-12-23 | 2017-01-03) 2: (2017-01-02 | 2017-01-04) 3: (2017-01-30 | 2017-02-04) => 1 and 2 should be combined (works perfekt, thanks again ;) ) and 3 should stand alone.

Comment: It seems that my changes don't really work. For January I get expected results but for May it combines for some reasons all the dates [SQL Fiddle with new holidays](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f03b/3/0)

Comment: Just noticed that you updated your answer. Thank you very much for your effort. But I have found out that the problem is MySQL 5.7. I get different results: 5.6 (as expected) and 5.7 is wrong (2016-12-23|2017-01-08; 2017-01-19|2017-01-19) => 2016-12-23|2017-01-19