# Best way to approach this MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I am running into an issue regarding the best query approach to solve a staff-member availability problem. I would like to return the availability for staff members on a certain date / time. The issue I am running into is that staff members can submit multiple time records for the same date. This means there may be "overlapping" records based on start & end time, and "non-overlapping" records. Below is a summary of my data structure:

**Table name:** availabilitySlots

**Data:**

| id | staffId | startTime | endTime | dayOfWeek | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-10-01 09:00:00 | 2023-10-01 13:00:00 | Monday | 2023-10-01 |
| 2 | 1 | 2023-10-01 13:00:00 | 2023-10-01 15:00:00 | Monday | 2023-10-01 |
| 3 | 2 | 2023-10-01 12:00:00 | 2023-10-01 14:00:00 | Monday | 2023-10-01 |
| 4 | 3 | 2023-10-01 09:00:00 | 2023-10-01 12:00:00 | Monday | 2023-10-01 |
| 5 | 3 | 2023-10-01 13:00:00 | 2023-10-01 15:00:00 | Monday | 2023-10-01 |
| 6 | 4 | 2023-10-01 15:00:00 | 2023-10-01 16:00:00 | Monday | 2023-10-01 |
| 7 | 4 | 2023-10-01 14:50:00 | 2023-10-01 17:30:00 | Monday | 2023-10-01 |
| 8 | 4 | 2023-10-01 17:20:00 | 2023-10-01 18:30:00 | Monday | 2023-10-01 |

I would like the query to return the following data:

| staffId | startTime | endTime | dayOfWeek | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-01 09:00:00 | 2023-10-01 15:00:00 | Monday | 2023-10-01 |
| 2 | 2023-10-01 12:00:00 | 2023-10-01 14:00:00 | Monday | 2023-10-01 |
| 3 | 2023-10-01 09:00:00 | 2023-10-01 12:00:00 | Monday | 2023-10-01 |
| 3 | 2023-10-01 13:00:00 | 2023-10-01 15:00:00 | Monday | 2023-10-01 |
| 4 | 2023-10-01 14:50:00 | 2023-10-01 18:30:00 | Monday | 2023-10-01 |

*For staffId=1 and staffId=4 you can see a range is returned for the MIN(startTime) AND MAX(endTime) across all availability records submitted for them on 2023-10-01

The issue I am running into is I can't get a range to be returned for when there are more than 2 records for a staff member, like in the case of staffId=4. I can however get a query to return a range when a staffId has 2 records (like staffId=1), however staff members can have multiple records on a given date, so I need a query to handle this.

I am decent at SQL, but this query is outside of my ability. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why doesn't `MIN(startTime)` and `MAX(endTime)` work for `staffId=4`?

Comment: I think the one you need help with is `staffId=3`, because there's a gap when they're not available.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to prohibit overlapping records in the first place? Let them change the start/end time of a record rather than adding an overlapping record.

Comment: @Barmar - A staff member may have 2 shifts they are able to work on a given date: 9am - 12pm, and then 4pm - 8pm. So you can't just use the Min(startTime) and Max(endTime) for staffId=4 on 10/1/2023 for example, because they are not available from 12pm - 4pm. That's why if the endTime of one record = the startTime of another record for the same staff member, then it would qualify to be a range. Like in the case of staffId=1 in my example data above. In the case it does not, then it would be 2 ranges for 1 staff member on 1 date. Hopefully that clarifies it

Comment: That's what I said -- 3 has non-overlapping shifts, not 4.

Comment: But if you don't allow them to create overlapping shifts, you don't need a special query. Just return the table contents.

Comment: Yes, we could always prevent them from creating overlapping shifts as that's a solution, but at this moment I am just looking for a query that can hopefully return what I'm asking for

Comment: Related, maybe duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38313853/how-to-combine-overlapping-date-ranges-in-mysql

Comment: "I would like to return the availability for staff members on a certain date / time." your question doesn't actually show this part?  please do.  it sounds like you are first trying to combine overlapping records and your question focuses on that; don't do that, it isn't required to solve this problem.  I'm guessing your "certain date / time" is actually a range?

Comment: Yes, that is the end goal, however I am just using this 1 date as a sample set of dummy data for my problem. First I would just like to return the availability on 10/1, and combine the overlapping records when possible, and see the data returned as displayed in the 2nd table of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH
cte1 AS (  -- set timepoints weights (in = +1, out = -1)
  SELECT staffId, startTime timepoint, 1 weight FROM availabilitySlots
  UNION ALL
  SELECT staffId, endTime, -1 FROM availabilitySlots
),
cte2 AS (  -- calculate overall timepoint weight
  SELECT staffId, timepoint, 
         SUM(weight) OVER (PARTITION BY staffId ORDER BY timepoint) cum_weight
  FROM cte1
),
cte3 AS (  -- detect combined range start
  SELECT staffId, timepoint, 
         CASE WHEN LAG(cum_weight) OVER (PARTITION BY staffId ORDER BY timepoint) > 0 
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
              END is_start
  FROM cte2
),
cte4 AS (  -- divide timepoints to groups/ranges
  SELECT staffId, timepoint, 
         SUM(is_start) OVER (PARTITION BY staffId ORDER BY timepoint) group_no
  FROM cte3
)
  -- find range boundaries (min and max timepoint in a group)
SELECT staffId, MIN(timepoint) startTime, MAX(timepoint) endTime
FROM cte4
GROUP BY staffId, group_no
ORDER BY 1,2
```

| staffId | startTime | endTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-01 09:00:00 | 2023-10-01 15:00:00 |
| 2 | 2023-10-01 12:00:00 | 2023-10-01 14:00:00 |
| 3 | 2023-10-01 09:00:00 | 2023-10-01 12:00:00 |
| 3 | 2023-10-01 13:00:00 | 2023-10-01 15:00:00 |
| 4 | 2023-10-01 14:50:00 | 2023-10-01 18:30:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_LY8ok04)

`dayOfWeek` and `date` columns values can be calculated from `startTime` column value.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much, this is exactly what I need. Yes, the dayOfWeek and date columns aren't really necessary like you said, just makes it a bit easier for reporting. Thank you again